Is there a screen recording program that is triggered by activity?
I am looking for a screen recording program for 22.04 (or 20.04) which can run in the background and be triggered by screen activity.
For example, I run the program and do not use the computer. After x seconds, the program stops recording. I start to use the internet, open notepad, use the terminal, etc - it records. I stop and after x seconds of inactivity, it also stops recording.
The reason I want the trigger is because otherwise the recorder might record GBs of nothing happening.
SimpleScreenRecorder has many options but an activity trigger is not one of them.

Could try using https://www.semicomplete.com/projects/xdotool to detect mouse movement, then launch the recorder. Poll again for movement and stop if none for x seconds? See also https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/49546/bash-script-to-detect-and-record-mouse-movements/49548
